# closed sets and continuous functions

Tags: general-topology

Which of the following statements are true?

$(a)$ Let $g\in C[0,1]$ be fixed. Then the set $A=\bigg\{f\in C[0,1] \ | \ \int_0^1 f(t)g(t)dt =0\bigg\}$ is closed in $C[0,1]$.

$(b)$ Let $g\in C_c(\mathbb{R})$ be fixed. Then the set $A=\bigg\{f\in C_c(\mathbb{R}) \ | \ \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t)g(t)dt =0\bigg\}$ is closed in $C_c(\mathbb{R})$. Here $C_c(\mathbb{R})$ means space of all continuous functions with compact support on $\mathbb{R}$.

$(c)$ Let $g\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ be fixed. Then the set $A=\bigg\{f\in L^2(\mathbb{R}) \ | \ \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t)g(t)dt =0\bigg\}$ is closed in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$.

I can't proceed merely using the definition of closed sets because the given sets involve functions and closed sets are those sets whose limit points are the points of the set itself. Do we need to consider a convergent sequence and proceed? If so, how to proceed the argument in that case?

Comment: Try to show that they are the preimage of a closed set under a continuous map

Comment: Are you clear what the topologies you are using on $C[0,1]$ etc.?

Answer (score 1):

To expand on Pere's comment, you want to use the fact that zero sets of continuous functions are closed. Let's do the first one.

So define the function $H: C([0,1]) \to \mathbb{R}$ by $H(f) = \displaystyle \int_0^1 f(t)g(t)dt$ (recall that $g$ is fixed).

It's easy to see that $H$ is continuous. For fix $\epsilon >0$. Set $\int_0^1 g(t)dt = M$. Then for $\|f_1 - f_2 \| < \displaystyle \frac{\epsilon}{M}$, where $f_1, f_2 \in C([0,1])$, we have that

$|H(f_1) -H(f_2)| \le \|f_1-f_2\| \int_0^1 g(t)dt < \epsilon$. Then $H$ is continuous, so its zero set -- $A$-- is closed.

The other problems are quite similar.